# How to validate for English alphabet characters only

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, coldfusion, jquery-validate

I have a textfield on a page which allows people to enter their name. This then gets included in a URL specially made for them e.g. `mysite.net/johnnyfive`

I don't want people to use any special characters in their name, including characters from non-English alphabets such as Arabic or Chinese.

How would I validate for the [English alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet) in **ColdFusion**? I came up with this for English names `#REReplace(LCase(ARGUMENTS.Name), '[^a-z0-9]', '', 'ALL')#` to ensure only characters A-Z and numbers are allowed. But if someone has entered in something like `نازنین` then I want to it reject it outright rather than trying to replace it.

I'd also like to do this on the jQuery side and bind it to the textfield so that it throws an error when someone tries to enter in a non-English character. I suppose even diacritic characters such as `á` should not be allowed.

I am using ColdFusion 10, jQuery 1.9, and jQuery Validate

Comment: By stating that you do not want people to enter 'non-English' characters, you are, essentially, telling some users that they will need to purposely misspell their name in order to use your application. This is a horrible user experience. A better solution might include using some kind of server side process that attempts to translate the user's  name into 'English' and then use that, or, instead of using the user's name, have a form field that they can enter what they want as that part of the URL and only allow 'English; characters there.

Comment: They're not mis-spelling their names as such. There will be people with Thai names for example that are written in the Thai alphabet. All they have to do is spell it using English characters. Its nothing that most people aren't already used to.

Comment: If the user's name is Carlos Peña, your business rules will force him to spell it Carlos Pena - which is NOT how it is spelled. Therefore, your business rules would force him to purposely misspell his name. I understand this is easier, but not an ideal solution. I prefer to do things right rather than easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same regex to validate the fields. Add anchors around the regex to ensure that nothing is presceded or followed by the string matched by the regex

```
^[^a-z0-9]$
```

- `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `$` anchors regex at the end of  the string.

Example : http://regex101.com/r/tJ7tJ9/1

You can use the match function to ensure that the string matches the regex

Example

```
var str = "نازنین"; 
if(str.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/gi))
{
    //Do something 
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: thank you @nu11p01n73R I've used this regex and it seems to be working

Comment: @volumeone You are welcome :) glad to hear i was of some help

Comment: My final solution on the ColdFusion side was to do a conditional statement checking the name like this `<cfif REFindNoCase("[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]+$", ARGUMENTS.Firstname) GT 0>...rejectname... </cfif>` for non-English alphabet characters. If a value is returned, then the name is rejected

Comment: So let me get this straight, @volumeone ... you'd reject Mr Peña's name, but R2D2 would be OK? [boggle].

Comment: @AdamCameron yes that's correct. until I figure out a way to convert Peña into Pena.

Comment: You still never really explained why you're doing this in the first place. I got in trouble for calling the *idea* kinda r**ist (not *you*: the *idea*) and my comment was deleted by the over-protective but under-intellectually-equipped censors, unfortunately along with the rest of the comment, which was asking for clarification of this. (NB: yes, I should have used the term "culturally insensitive", but it amounts to the same observation, and not really key to most of what I was asking).

Comment: You need not include both `A-Z` and `a-z` if using `REFindNoCase()` - one or the other will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the DeAccent UDF (java):

http://www.cflib.org/udf/deAccent

```
<cfscript>
function deAccent(str){
    var Normalizer = createObject("java","java.text.Normalizer");
    var NormalizerForm = createObject("java","java.text.Normalizer$Form");
    var normalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, createObject("java","java.text.Normalizer$Form").NFD);
    var pattern = createObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").compile("\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(normalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
</cfscript>
```

and then perform a string compare:

```
if (originalString NEQ deAccent(originalString)){
   writeOutput("Invalid String");
}
```

If you wanted to validate using jQuery, it could be performed with an ajax request to the ColdFusion server.  You should probably do this to ensure that the string is unique as you stated that you plan on creating sub-directories/virtual paths.